# Versions of Lusin theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, reference-request, borel-measures

I found this two version of Lusin theorem, without reference

Can someone know in any book i can found it :

> Theorem 1: Let $(X,\beta,\mu)$ a measurable space satisfying:
>
> $\bullet$ $X$ is a metric space locally compact,
>
> $\bullet$  $\beta$ is a borelian  $\sigma-$algebra.
>
> $\bullet$ $\mu$ is a regular measure.
>
> Suppose that $A\in \beta$ such that $\mu(A)<+\infty.$ Then, given
>   $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $g\in C_0(X)$ such that
>
> $\bullet$ $\mu(\{x\in X; g(x)\neq \chi_{A}(x)\})<\varepsilon;$
>
> $\bullet$ $g(x)\in [0,1], x\in X.$

and the second:

> Theorem 2:
>
> $(i)$ $Y$ be a Hausdorff topological space with a countable  bases;
>
> $(ii)$ $(\Omega,\beta,\mu)$ a finite measurable space, where 
>   $\Omega\subset Y$;
>
> $(iii)$ $f:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$ a measurable  function.    Given
>   $\varepsilon>0$, there exists a compact set $K\subset \Omega$  such
>   that
>
> $(I)$ $f$ is continuous on $K$;
>
> $(II)$  $\mu(\Omega\setminus K)<\varepsilon.$

Comment: Bogachev's *Measure Theory* comes close.

Comment: @kimchilover in any page please